# Please any one help me to clear this error

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu

```
~/aptos_prog/first_app$ npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/god/.npm/_logs/2022-08-30T13_31_04_860Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1426547/edit) your question including content of `/home/god/.npm/_logs/2022-08-30T13_31_04_860Z-debug-0.log`

Comment: Please also add information on your system version, and about how you installed npm.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.